# Flutter align one children in column to extreme right and others on center

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-row, flutter-column

Could you please help me to align one element in column to extreme right.

[image]

Please help me

Comment: please provide more details with your own code implementation. No one here can help you without proper information in question. I am confused on about what you want. Please edit question with more brief

Comment: please include your code too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap that icon with `Align` and set alignment to `centerRight` , like this:

```
 IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.info,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.lock_clock),
                  Text('item 1'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            VerticalDivider(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.info,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.lock_clock),
                  Text('item 1'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            VerticalDivider(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.info,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.lock_clock),
                  Text('item 1'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

[image]

Or If you want that icon attach to top right of column in overlay, you can wrap the column wit stack widget and set that icon in it, like this:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.lock_clock),
                            Text('item 1'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.info,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                        top: 0,
                        right: 0,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                VerticalDivider(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.lock_clock),
                            Text('item 1'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.info,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                        top: 0,
                        right: 0,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                VerticalDivider(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.lock_clock),
                            Text('item 1'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.info,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                        top: 0,
                        right: 0,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
```

[image]

This make icon closer to column.

Comment: Many thanks for you response. Unfortunately I don’t have my laptop with me now. That’s why I couldn’t post my code. In the column i want to add another icon on top and align to extreme right. That’s where i am struggling with. Thanks

Comment: o I see now, I updated my answer, check it out

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Expanded(child: SizedBox());
```

Before the wudget that you want to move in the most right